# Attribute Error when using self

Tags: python-3.x, self

I have this small script implementing a single class with two functions. I wanted to simply print a value that was found in the first function from the second function when I call it from outside of the class.

**Problem**
It seemed really simple after reading this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698030/what-does-self-do?noredirect=1&lq=1) over self, but nothing I try seems to be working. I keep getting attribute errors:

```
class search:
   def test(self):
      self.here = 'hi'
      self.gone = 'bye'
      self.num = 12

   def tester(self):
      return "{}".format(self.here)

s = search()
s.tester()
print (s.gone)
```

Returns...

> AttributeError: 'search' object has no attribute 'here'

**Question**
How can I modify this script to achieve the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define 'here'

```
class search:
   here=None
   def __init__(self):
     self.here='hi'

   def test(self):
     ...
```

Comment: I want to retain the values assigned in the first function though. This just makes that global variable null and prints nothing.

Comment: then use constructor __ init __ to set values, updated

Comment: Ah, thats what i was looking for. Sorry, new to python.

Comment: Great! Welcome to python, have fun.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you never execute the function test(self) which initiate the variable. you can call it using s.test() before s.tester()